# Как передать метод с this из одного компонента в другой в React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Как передать `метод с this` из одного компонента в другой?

Мне нужно из компонента `Editor` передать в `компонент Modal` `метод save` `компонента Editor`, но при передаче `this` теряется и выдаёт в консоли `undefined`.

Я привязывал контекст при помощи `bind` в конструкторе класса `Editor`, но это не сработало.

Editor:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Modal from "../modal";
import $ from "jquery";

export default class Editor extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();    
    this.state = {
      pageList: [],
      newPageName: "",
      loading: true
    };
    this.save = this.save.bind(this); //не работает
  }

  render() {
    const { pageList, loading } = this.state;
    const modal = true;
    return (
      <>
        <ConfirmModal modal={modal} target={"modal-save"} method={this.save} />
      </>
    );
  }
}
```

Modal:

```
import React from "react";

const ConfirmModal = ({ modal, target, method }) => {
  return (
    <div id={target} uk-modal={modal.toString()}>
      <div>
        <h2>Сохранение</h2>
        <p>Вы действительно хотите сохранить изменения?</p>
        <p>
          <button>Отменить</button>
          <button
            onClick={() =>
              method(
                // ******* Уведомление об успешном
                // сохранении
                () => {
                  UIkit.notification({
                    message: "Успешно сохранено!",
                    status: "success"
                  });
                },
                // ******* Уведомление об ошибке
                () => {
                  UIkit.notification({
                    message: "Ошибка сохранения!",
                    status: "danger"
                  });
                }
              )
            }
          >
            Сохранить
          </button>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default ConfirmModal;
```

Так тоже писал, но не работает:

```
<ConfirmModal modal={modal} target={'modal-save'} method={this.save.bind(this)} />
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Определите сам метод `save` для того что бы Вам было что передавть:

```
constructor() {
    super()    
    this.state = {
      pageList: [],
      newPageName: "",
      loading: true
    }
    this.save = this.save.bind(this) // работает
}

save() {}  // определите сам метод
```